# Join large table to small in SQL Server with clustered columnstore index takes too long

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, azure-sql-database, inner-join

I am experiencing very slow performance when trying to join 2 tables: one has 39M rows, the other 10k (35 sec). This runs on Azure SQL Premium instance, which is very decent server

```
select m39.* 
from [Table_With_39M_Rows] m39 
inner join [Table_With_10K_Rows] k10 on m39.[Id] = k10.[Id]
```

even a `count(*)` takes around 10 seconds

```
select count(*) 
from [Table_With_39M_Rows] m39 
inner join [Table_With_10K_Rows] k10 on m39.[Id] = k10.[Id]
```

Here are the table details:

- Table `[Table_With_39M_Rows]` has around 39 million rows (50 columns) with a clustered columnstore index:

  ```
  CREATE CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX CCI_Table_With_39M_Rows 
     ON Table_With_39M_Rows
  CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED UNCI_Table_With_39M_Rows_Id (Id ASC)
  ```
- Table `[Table_With_10K_Rows]` has around 10k rows (50 columns) and `Id` as the primary key

  ```
  ALTER TABLE Table_With_10K_Rows 
      ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Table_With_10K_Rows 
      PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([Id] ASC)
  ```

[image]

Clustered ColumnsStore index scan takes 99% and slows everything down.

How can I optimize this particular join? What indexing strategy should I employ?

Comment: As a baseline, how long does the `COUNT(*)` take without the join?  Also, why are you mixing column store with `*`?  One key advantage of column store is that you don't need to read the fields you're not using, but then you go an use them ***all***?  If you don't ***need*** the column store, then just having a `CLUSTERED` index on `m39.id` will ensure both tables are ordered the same, allowing a `MERGE` join, which is about the fastest you can get.

Comment: COUNT(*) takes no time at all. I need columnstore for other purposes.

Comment: Then what about `SELECT m39.id` instead of `SELECT m39.*`?  *(By the way, "no time at all" is extremely subjective when providing information to support helping you, please provide objective measurements, in milliseconds rather than in throw away comments?)*

Comment: My experience of Column Store databases is mostly Amazon Redshift.  That has the ability to define the ordering of the rows in the Column Store.  From what I'm readying for SQL Server 2016 on-wards it's possible to do something like : Create the table with a clustered primary key on `id`, then populate the table, then apply the `CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE INDEX`.  When done in that order it appears that the row order is maintained for maximum performance when joining on `id`.  You'' have to experience and research that though.

Comment: SELECT m39.id with the same join takes 10sec, compared to 35sec with m39.* . But even 10sec is too long for the query what returns no rows

Comment: Well, you're still isolating the performance profile.  `*` is responsible for 25s of the elapsed time, and you can ignore that, the more columns you select the longer a column store takes, it's the law *(they're designed exactly for that, to be faster the fewer columns you select)*.  Now to improve the performance of the `SELECT m39.id FROM m39 INNER JOIN 10k` *(such as attempting to force the row order, as I described immediately above you recent comment)*.  For that query, please could you include the entire execute plan?

Comment: I think this is actually what you need to read : [Columnstore indexes - Query performance](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-query-performance) *(it includes an example on forcing the ordering of a column store)*  If you have inserted data in batches, or any other activity that has prevented the row order being as desired, you may need to use `ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE` to re-assert the row ordering. [Columnstore indexes - defragmentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-defragmentation)

Comment: Just because a query returns zero rows does not mean it will be fast.

Comment: @user1153896:Were you able to try any of below solutions or did you found anything new ?

Answer (score 0):

Clustered column store indexes are helpful **if row group elimination works**(you can think of this skipping entire segment of rows which don't satisfy predicate) and if queries are analytical in nature.

To check whether segment elimination is occurring, you  can use below queries

**Below is a sample demo for a query i have(since we don't have your test data) which may help you understand more**

**query:**

```
select s.* from sales s
join
numbers n
on n.number=s.id
```

Numbers table only has 65356 rows and sales table has more than 3 million rows.Each segment can have only one million rows.If you can observe the output of `statistics IO`,SQLSERVER reads 2 segments(2 million rows) and 2  segments are skipped,which is not great and i expect only one segment to be read and remaining three segments to be skipped..But 2 are read as shown below

```
Table 'sales'. Segment reads 2, segment skipped 2.
```

This is happening because you might have created clustered column store from a heap ,so try doing below

drop your existsing clustered column store index,in my case it is

```
drop index nci on sales
```

now try creating clustered index first and clustered column store next,this helps sqlserver in inserting the rows in order into clustered column store index.. you might also want to use maxdop 1 to avoid parallelism and unordered rows

```
create clustered index  nci on sales(id)

create clustered columnstore index nci  on sales
with (drop_existing=on,maxdop =1)
```

if you run the query now, you can see segement elimiation occurs and query is fast

```
Table 'sales'. Segment reads 1, segment skipped 2.
```

**References and further reading:**
https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2017/01/30/columnstore-segment-elimination/
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2016/07  /17/columnstore-index-how-do-they-defer-from-traditional-btree-indices-on-rowstore-tables/
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/columnstore-index-performance-rowgroup-elimination/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you be consistent on use of [].

ID for a foreign key is not a good name.

[Columnstore Indexes Described](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088(v=sql.120).aspx)

> Columnstore indexes give high performance gains for queries that use
>   full table scans, and are not well-suited for queries that seek into
>   the data, searching for a particular value.

Just because you need columnstore for other purposes does not make it a good applications for this.

Try regular nonclustered index on [Table_With_39M_Rows].[ID]